# Render through camera results in dark, noisy image

Tags: rendering

I recently started playing around with rendering in blender a bit. I quickly figured some things out I never used in modelling.
However, after the first time rendering an image through a camera, I noticed something odd. When I render the view through Rendered Viewport Shading, it looks good (Image 1). If I render it through the camera however, the image I get is very dark and insanely noisy (Image 2).
I am sure it has something do to with the camera settings, but I don't know what or how.

I would appreciate if someon could give me a hint as to what might be missing there.

This is the blender file I am using: [image]

Thanks, Titan

[image: Image rendered through viewpart shading]

[image: Image rendered through camera]

Comment: Each shading mode has options for lighting and if you have the options set differently than the render you might have problems.  If it's not that, can you share a blend file that shows the problem so we can look at your settings? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: Look up the options of the *Viewport Shading*. You're using a Studio Light in your viewport previews while there's no HDRI in the actual scene, resulting in the dark render of your second image.

Comment: Added the blender file to the initila question. Any help appreciated! :)

Comment: unfortunately you did not file -> external data -> pack resources before uploading...